# wordpress posts doesn't retrieve on custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I created a custom template php file and made a page that uses this template.

In this template I want to show my blog posts, I copied the same lines of code than my front page to retrieve them, but it didn’t works.

It shows a unclickable link instead of my blog posts : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvOlz.jpg

How can i fix that ?

I tried to put the code into the page it self but it din't works.

there is the list.php that i use as template and didn't works

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: list
*/
?>

<?php wp_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


   <div class="blogo">
        <h4> <?php the_category(); ?> <h4>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>             
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> > See the post </a>

   </div>
     <?php endwhile;>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On page template you need to call wp_query loop for fetch posts of any post type.
I have updated your code for getting posts on page by using Page Template -

```
<?php /* Template Name: list */ ?>

<?php
get_header();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        ?>
    <div class="blogo">
        <h4> <?php the_category(); ?> <h4>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" > See the post </a>
    </div>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
get_footer();
?>
```